# Alternative to pointers in Java

Tags: java, c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void decrease(int *i);
int main(){
    int i = 10;
    decrease(&i);
    printf("%d",i);
}
void decrease(int *i){
    *i = *i - 1;
}
```

What would be the Java program for the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you pointed out (no pun intended), Java does not support pointers.  So, there is no way to directly manipulate the value of a primitive passed to a method, because only a copy of the primitive would be used in the method.  One way to get around this would be to just return the updated value, and then overwrite the integer in the calling scope:

```
public static int decrease(int i) {
    return i - 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 10;
    i = decrease(i);
    System.out.println(i);  // prints 9
}
```

Comment: `return i - 1;` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I guess it might avoid an implicit assignment, which isn't really needed.  I only used `--i` for brevity, that is all.

Comment: It's not wrong, but it is misleading. People reading it would wonder why you're updating `i`. Dumber (or less experienced) people might change it to `return i--;` thinking the result would be the same. `return i - 1;` leaves no potential confusion, hence my use of "more appropriate".

Answer (score 6):

You have two options, either (return) the value, and modify it in the main class, or pass an Object, not a primitive.

An object with your values:

```
public class Holder {
    public int x;
}
```

And a method to modify it

```
public void modify(Holder h){
    h.x = 2;
}
```

Called like:

```
Holder h = new Holder();
h.x = 1;

modify(h);
System.out.println(h.x);
```

Results in:

> 2

Comment: Or an array with 1 element would also do the job